# Setting visibilty of an image in my Second Activity to VISIBLE from my Main Activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my button in Main Activity that is supposed to change the visibility of and ImageView in Activity 2 from INVISIBLE to VISIBLE. I didn't study yet how to transfer information from one activity to another. **This is essentially all I've done so far:**

```
  final Button getAchievement = findViewById(R.id.achievementButton);
    final Button achievementActivity = findViewById(R.id.achievementActivity);
    final ImageView achievementImage = findViewById(R.id.achievementImage);

    getAchievement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You unlocked this achievement!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                achievementImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    achievementActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Achievements.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So probably the easiest way to achieve it is to use an `Intent` one of the basic method to navigate through your application. More about Intents [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

I wrote a simple application which I hope will help you to understand the usage of the Intent and how to send data between activities.

First the *activity_main.xml*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeState"
        android:text="Change state"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:text="GO!"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the *MainActivity.java* file.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int state = View.GONE;
    public static final String STATE_MESSAGE = "ImageViewState";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // consider to use a switch in an improved version since it has only two states
        Button changeState = findViewById(R.id.changeState);
        changeState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (state == View.GONE){
                    state = View.VISIBLE;
                } else {
                    state = View.GONE;
                }
            }

        });

        Button nextActivity = findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
        nextActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(STATE_MESSAGE, state);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now the *activity_second.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the *SecondActivity.java* which in its onCreate method sets the visibility of the ImageView based on the state.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setVisibility(getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.STATE_MESSAGE, 0));
    }
}
```

To go back to the MainActivity use the back button on your phone.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can create Local [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) and send information from one activity to another

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences to store some key i.e. flag.
Set the flag to true in the onclick...nd store that flag boolean value in your sharedpreference

In your 2nd activity, read the boolean value from SP. and if flag is true then handle the visibility of your view accordingly.

Link for SharedPreferences:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences